# Reference random user information in another class

Tags: c#, testing

I am trying to reference some random users generated in one class I made in another class where I am going to use them.

```
public static void RandUserName(string domain, string FullName, string Email)
            {
                string firstName = "";
                string lastName = "";
                string phone = "";
                RandomUserName(domain, firstName, lastName, Email, phone);
                FullName = String.Format("{0} {1}.com", firstName, lastName);
        }

Public static void RandName(string FirstName, string LastName)
        {            
            string[] maleNames = new string [1000]{"aaron", "abdul", "abe", "abel"}; 
            string[] femaleNames = new string [1000] {"abby", "abigail", "ada"};
            string[] lastNames = new string[1000] {"abbott", "acevedo", "acosta"};

Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
            if (rand.Next(1, 2) == 1)
            {
                FirstName = maleNames[rand.Next(0, maleNames.Length-1)];
            }
            else
            {
                FirstName = femaleNames[rand.Next(0, femaleNames.Length-1)];
            }
        }

 public static string RandomUserName(string Domain, string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string phone)
        {
            RandName(FirstName, LastName);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain))
            {
                Domain = String.Format("{0}{1}.com", FirstName, LastName);
            }

            Email = "Tester" + LastName + "@" + Domain;
            phone = "850-555-1234";
            return FirstName;
        }
```

Here is where I want to reference these names to in VB.net. I am trying to translate this to c#, these come from a request I am making:

```
                RandInfo.RandomUserName(Domain, .PrimaryContact.FirstName, .PrimaryContact.LastName, .PrimaryContact.Email, .PrimaryContact.Phone)
                RandInfo.RandomUserName(Domain, .BillingContact.FirstName, .BillingContact.LastName, .BillingContact.Email, .BillingContact.Phone)
                RandInfo.RandomUserName(Domain, .TechContact.FirstName, .TechContact.LastName, .TechContact.Email, .TechContact.Phone)
                RandInfo.RandomUserName(Domain, .EmergencyContact.FirstName, .EmergencyContact.LastName, .EmergencyContact.Email, .EmergencyContact.Phone)
```

Sorry if all this is confusing! Please ask any questions you have to understand and help!

Comment: What are you trying to pass to the `RandomUserName` function? Are those variables that you set before you made the call? Do you want those values to change or remain the same? Have you considered whether or not to pass values [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: i think you may have misunderstood the concept of functions/method. The `void` in your 'RandUserName' function is where you would declare the return type.

A small example:

```
public string GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

A call like this:

```
GetFullName("John", "Doe")
```

would return "John Doe". An (ugly) alternative way would be to declare the parameters in your methods as out parameters, but i would try to avoid that.

What you want to achieve can be done in various way, i would start with designing a `User` class with properties for `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone` and so on.

Then you could create a function that generates instances of this class, its properties filled with random values. 
But i guess you would have to put some effort into it for yourself.